# How to get next samlest value after giver value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing system to loan lending company witch when customer delaying there payment they add additional rate to installment amount.

**Example:** *Let's say that customer delayed the payment for 3 days now company adding additional 2.5% to installment next let's say 5 days then it's 3.5% so it's going like that*

```
+-------+------+------+---------------------+
| dd_id | rate | days | time                |
+-------+------+------+---------------------+
|     1 | 2.50 |    3 | 2018-07-12 23:42:11 |
|     2 | 3.50 |    5 | 2018-07-12 23:42:11 |
|     3 | 4.50 |    7 | 2018-07-12 23:42:11 |
|     4 | 5.50 |    9 | 2018-07-12 23:42:11 |
+-------+------+------+---------------------+
```

Until now I was able to retrieve some data using this SQL query and with this number of days

```
SELECT * FROM delaying WHERE days >= 5 LIMIT 1
```

** (5 = number of days delayed)**

Now problem begins when number of delayed days grater than values in table it doesn't return any value and I tried to change the sign but then it's return **3**. Is there any way to retrieve biggest value after given value let's say **11** then it's should return **9**

Comment: If the delay is 6 days - which row should be returned?

Comment: it should return 7

Comment: But if the delay is 2 days it should return nothing? I don't see any logic here.

Comment: yep now that's the problem.... now i am just going to put a `if(days_delayed >3){ stuff}` in there so it's will only check the database if the number of delayed days greater that 3

Answer (score 1):

First, your query is not correct.  You need an `order by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM delaying
WHERE days >= 5
ORDER BY days
LIMIT 1 ;
```

If your table is not very big, you can follow a similar approach using `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM delaying
ORDER BY (days >= 5) DESC, ABS(days - 5) ASC
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: another small problem now it's returning even number of days are less than delayed lest say if i enter 2 it should not return any value